# Getting Image Source from ListBox SelectedIndex on navigation in C#

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I have a ListBox bind with images from SampleData source. On selection of the ListBox Item, I want to display the image in next page so I have passed the SelectedIndex on navigation but I am unable to get the image or display it. My code is below:`

//AlbumImages.cs

public class AlbumImages: ObservableCollection
    {

```
}
```

//AlbumImage.cs

public class AlbumImage
    {
        public string title { get; set; }

```
    public string content { get; set; }  
}
```

//App.xaml.cs

```
    private static MainViewModel viewModel = null;

    public AlbumImages albumImages = new AlbumImages();

    public int selectedImageIndex;
```

//MainPage.xaml.cs

```
    private void listBoxPhoto_SelectionChanged(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (listBoxPhoto.SelectedIndex == -1) return;

        this.NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Photogallery.xaml?SelectedIndex=" + listBoxPhoto.SelectedIndex, UriKind.Relative));
    }
```

//Photogallery.xaml.cs

```
    // Reference to App

    private App app = App.Current as App;

protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
    {

    base.OnNavigatedTo(e);

        IDictionary<string, string> parameters = this.NavigationContext.QueryString;

        if (parameters.ContainsKey("SelectedIndex"))
        {
            app.selectedImageIndex = Int32.Parse(parameters["SelectedIndex"]);

        }
        else
        {
            app.selectedImageIndex = 0;
        }
    LoadImage();
}
     private void LoadImage()
    {
    BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
    bitmapImage.UriSource=new Uri(app.albumImages[app.selectedImageIndex].content, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
    image.Source = bitmapImage;
}`
```

Comment: Not sure if you can pass SelectedItem as a parameter as it would be an object of what you are presenting in that listbox. Also you are missing and & before SelectedItem, which might be why you are having trouble getting that index.

Comment: can you show some more code? what is app.selectedImageIndex?

Comment: @ShoaibShaikh I have edited the code above. Actually I want to create a photo gallery inside my app.

Comment: this.NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Photogallery.xaml?SelectedIndex=" + listBoxPhoto.SelectedIndex, UriKind.Relative));

Try replace the Navigation code to the above.

Comment: @nkchandra I have tried with the navigation code you have given. Its getting the index but i am confused how to use this index for the displaying the image in Photogallery.xaml.

Comment: changes made by @Thaven should give you some clear idea on how to solve the problem. If your prob is still not solved, then show us some code how you are binding data to the Listbox

Comment: @nkchandra I didnt get any changes made by Thaven.

Comment: <ListBox Margin="31,8" x:Name="listBoxPhoto" ItemsSource="{Binding photoCollection}" VerticalAlignment="Center" d:LayoutOverrides="Width" SelectionChanged="listBoxPhoto_SelectionChanged" >

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve your requirement, you have to make the photoCollection globally available to Photogallery page as well.
You can do this by assigning a copy of photoCollection (which you are using to bind to Listbox) to albumImages of App.xaml.cs from your MainPage.xaml.cs page

Note: There were some changes made your code in the question (I am not sure who did those), but the code is very near to working.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to assign a copy of photoCollection to albumImages of App.xaml.cs from MainPage.xaml.cs page? I am confused.

Comment: //AlbumImages.cs

I have changed the ObservableCollection in AlbumImages.cs as `public class AlbumImages: ObservableCollection<photoCollection>
    {

    }` but i am not getting it.

Comment: I am not sure, what's your photoCollection is. I am assuming it as a List<AlbumImage> photoCollection;
In App.xaml.cs, add this
public List<AlbumImage> albumImages;
And in MainPage.xaml.cs, somewhere in the code(when you are sure that the photoCollection is available), add this
private App app = App.Current as App;
app.albumImages = photoCollection;

Now that you can access app.albumImages in Photogallery.xaml.cs as well

Comment: photoCollection is a collection of objects i.e. Id, Name and Image, present inside Sample Data Source called GalleryDataSource created using Expression Blend4 by importing an xml file.

Comment: If photoCollection is a SampleData source, I think that will be availalbe to phonegallery page as well. So you can access it like, 
phoneCollection.ElementAt(app.selectedImageIndex); if still you are confused, join this http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9092/windows-phone